SwiftUI .animation(:value:) does not work
Given the following view the favorite flag disappears, when showFavoriteFlag is set to false from outside - but that change is not animated. Why not? I'd expect the text "Test" to slide to the right, but instead it just appears there immediately, as soon as the favorite flag disappears.
struct HeaderComponent: View {
    let timestamp: Date

    @Binding var showFavoriteFlag: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TimestampComponent(for: timestamp)

            Spacer(minLength: 0)

            Text("Test")

            if showFavoriteFlag {
                FavoriteFlagComponent()
           }
        }
        .animation(.default, value: showFavoriteFlag)
    }
}

Update re: the requested MRE - this is (simplified) how I use the component in my app. Issue seems to be related to the ForEach as the animation works for the first header component as expected, but not for the two embedded ones:
import SwiftUI

struct HeaderComponent: View {
    @Binding var showFavoriteFlag: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Timestamp")

            Spacer(minLength: 0)

            Text("Test")

            if showFavoriteFlag {
                Text("Favorite")
            }
        }
        .animation(.default, value: showFavoriteFlag)
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var flags: [Bool] = [true, false]
    @Published var otherCondition: Int = 1

    func toggle() {
        for index in 0..<flags.count {
            flags[index].toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HeaderComponent(showFavoriteFlag: Binding.constant(model.otherCondition == 0 ? false : model.flags[0]))

            ForEach(model.flags, id: \.self) { flag in
                HeaderComponent(showFavoriteFlag: Binding.constant(model.otherCondition == 0 ? false : flag))
            }

            Button(action: { model.toggle() }, label: { Text("Toggle") })
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


I cannot reproduce by making basic assumptions. Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce your issue.

I added a copy & paste example above. Already helped me a little bit to zero in on the issue.

You should watch “Demystify SwiftUI”

I'll have a look, thank you!

A few changes you should make first:

HeaderComponent.showFavoriteFlag should not be a Binding. It can just be a regular let constant, since HeaderComponent does not modify it.
This means you also don't need to pass in Binding.constant(...). Just pass the value directly.
ContentView.model should be a @StateObject, not @ObservedObject.

With those changes, the ForEach now looks like this:
ForEach(model.flags, id: \.self) { flag in
    HeaderComponent(showFavoriteFlag: model.otherCondition == 0 ? false : flag)
}

When you toggle the model, the flags change from [true, false] to [false, true]. As far as ForEach is concerned, this means the two HeaderComponents swapped places with each other. After all, you have told it to use the flag values themselves to identify the views. The view with id true has moved to the second position, and the view with id false has moved to the first position. Add .animation(.default, value: model.flags) to the ForEach and you will see this animated.
That's obviously not what you want ForEach to think. When you toggle the model, you want showFavoriteFlag to change, but the views' identities to stay unchanged. Therefore, you should choose something else for the id: parameter - something that stays unchanged when you toggle.
See Demystifying SwiftUI for what identity means for a view.
If you don't plan on adding/removing things from flags, you can use the indices of the flags array as the id:
ForEach(model.flags.indices, id: \.self) { i in
    let flag = model.flags[i]
    HeaderComponent(showFavoriteFlag: model.otherCondition == 0 ? false : flag)
}

The indices do not change when you toggle. However, if you were to insert an element at the start of flags, ForEach will see this as adding an extra element at the end, since the ids change from [0, 1] to [0, 1, 2].
What you should use as the id here very much depends on your exact situation. If your real code is really just uses a [Bool], I would change this to an array of some Identifiable type, like:
struct IdentifiableBool: Identifiable {
    var bool: Bool
    let id = UUID()
}

Then you can use an array of this in ForEach, without passing the id parameter. The ForEach will use the id property (which is generated every time you initialise IdentifiableBool) to identify the views.

The "surroundings" I provided above were just a quick and dirty "abstraction" from how I use the component.  Unfortunately it came with some flaws... Anyhow I could consider some of your hints for my actual implementation as well and I could make the MRE work. I also managed to get it working in my app, though I still not happy with the workaround I applied. In my actual view I use two nested ForEach statement and as soon as I base the outer one on actual items of the array the animation breaks - I need to use the indices instead to iterate over the items. Anyhow - it works so far - thanks!

The issue in your code is that you loop over the flags (aka boolean values) which creates a weird animation, it replaces the 2nd HeaderComponent with the 3rd every time you toggle values.

Note that the HeaderComponent outside the ForEach loop does animate as expected.

To solve this, you can either loop over the count of the flags, or create an Identifiable flag struct, see example:

Loop over count:

ForEach(0..<model.flags.count, id: \.self) { i in
    //...
}


Create Flag struct:

struct Flag: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var bool: Bool
    var timestamp: Date
    
    mutating func toggle() {
        self.bool.toggle()
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var flags: [Flag] = [.init(bool: true, timestamp: .now),
                                    .init(bool: false, timestamp: .now)]

    //...
}

// Use it:
ForEach(model.flags) { flag in
    //...
}


This does not work - see updated question with MRE example above (just tried it out). Thanks anyway.
